# change the transparency of a movieclip object

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, movieclip

i've a MovieClip and i would like to change the transparency of this movieclip how can i do?
Thx.

Comment: @Nander : please click on the check mark if your problem has been solved. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using the _alpha property should do it. 0 = completely transparent, and 100 = opaque.

```
name_MC._alpha = 50;
```

Comment: like this ..?
canalFlexFlash.couleurDept = function(tabDptCouleur : Object)
{
//trace("_localConnection.couleurDept");
 for (i in _root) 
 {
  if (_root[i] instanceof MovieClip) 
  {
    var colorful = new Color(_root[i]);
    if (tabDptCouleur[_root[i]._name]!=null)
    {
      couleur = Number(tabDptCouleur[_root[i]._name]);
 _root[i]._alpha = 50;
    }
  }
}

Comment: I'm not sure what that function is, but you asked how to change the transparency of a movieclip. Of which the answer is shown above. if you need further clarification. mcName._alpha = 0 is completely transparent (invisible) and mcName._alpha = 100 is completely solid.